# RSA polynomial cubic root

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

Let's suppose we are given a linear polyonmial

$$\begin{align}f(x) = ax + b\end{align}$$
where a and b is known which satisfies this equation

$$\begin{align}y^3 - f(x) \equiv 0\mod(n) \end{align}$$ where n is RSA modulus.

Is there any way to solve for pair(x,y)?

Follow-up question: If there is restriction where only those values of x are allowed for which $$\begin{align}f(x)<n \end{align}$$

Comment: In $y^3 - f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, how are $x$ and $y$ related?  Are you looking for any $(x, y)$ pair that satisfies the equation?  Is $x$ a known constant?  Or, did you mean $y^3 - f(y) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$

Comment: yeah @poncho I am looking for any valid pair of (x,y) where x and y are natural numbers. I will update the question

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to solve for pair(x,y)?

If you're looking for an arbitrary pair, it's easy (assuming $a \ne 0$).

- Pick an arbitrary $y$
- Solve for $f(x) = y^3$; that'd be $x = a^{-1}(y^3 - b) \pmod{n}$

You're done.

Comment: If we had to find for smallest value possible of x, then can we do it?

Comment: why do u think that x will not be smallest? when You stated ${f(x)<n}$, and a, b are constant.

Comment: @SauravKumarSingh: if $y$ happened to have a cube root modulo $n$ (which it will quite a lot of the time), then a solution with $x=0$ will be minimal.  However, finding that solution would imply solving the RSA problem with $e=3$; that's a hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

Generate and output any arbitrary pair $(x,y)$.

There is always some $f$, which would fulfill the question and the follow-up question. It even works with fixing $a=1$, and looking for the appropriate $b$, s.t. your equations are fulfilled. And some $b$ always exist, regardless of $x,y$